# How to use ConEmuC with posh-git

Tags: powershell, conemu

posh-git provides a great prompt, showing git status.

[image]

But I want to add `ConEmuC -StoreCW` to my `prompt$` so I can use `%d` and have my ConEmu tabs update. Note in pic above how the tab did not reflect the `cd ..` command.

The samples here overwrite the posh-git prompt if I put them in my $profile ps1 file.

https://conemu.github.io/en/PowershellPrompt.html

Comment: The link above contains examples for proper CD processing. What have you tried?

Comment: I was running posh-git .7.  The ability to override the prompt is a 1.0 feature. I've now upgraded and have it working.

Comment: Calls of ConEmuC are less effective than ANSI.